# Doesn't' seem to be a valid storyboard - xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode4.2, storyboard

I have a problem with my application that use the storyboard.
I have a master view and a detail view (that is open when I press button on master view); all work correctly and when i press the button on the master view the detail view is opening but only for 17 times!!
At the 18th times that i press button the application crash an I have this error message:

```
'nsinvalidargumentexception' reason 'there doesn't' seem to be a valid storyboard at path....
```

Please help me!! :)

Stefano

Comment: Did you try Product - Clean ?

Comment: Cleaning worked for me

Answer (score 2):

"Product -> Clean" should solve this problem.
At least it helped in my case.